# How to use OR in criteria with countif functions?

Tags: regex, google-sheets-formula, match, counting, countif

How to say find the word "Apple" or "Orange" by using or in the criteria instead of typing +countif as another criteria? I mean adding OR in the same criteria.

```
=countif(A1:A100,"apple|Orange")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(REGEXMATCH(A1:A100, "apple|Orange"))
```

to make it case insensitive use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(REGEXMATCH(A1:A100, "(?i)apple|Orange"))
```

[image]

Comment: it didn't work https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1igpVP462erYL_uZ3OFMlwjOgKdUFFiTe_kYzdeX8mHw/edit#gid=0

Comment: It worked. Cant REGEXMATCH be used with countif?

Comment: @HassanAlmaateeq no need for COUNTIF because REGEXMATCH outputs TRUE/FALSE which is equal to 1/0 and then SUMPRODUCT will just convert it internally to 1/0 and sum it outputting the "count"

Comment: Let me rephrase my issue and i apologize if i couldn't explain it well. If I used countifs in this way. 'COUNTIFS(A1:A100,REGEXMATCH(A1:A100,"(?i)apple|orange"), B1:B100, "banana")' . I routinely do it in this way: countifs(A1:A100, "apple",B1:B100, "banana"+countifs(A1:A100, "orange", B1:B100, "banana")

Comment: Ok I figured it out: arrayformula(countifs(REGEXMATCH(A1:A100," (?i)apple|orange"), true, regexmatch(B1:B100, "(?i)banana"),true))

Comment: Since count if is case insensitive,  I can remove the second REGEXMATCH

Comment: @HassanAlmaateeq `=SUMPRODUCT(REGEXMATCH(A1:A100, "(?i)apple|Orange"), B1:B100="banana")`

Comment: So, sumproduct is easier than countif and I can do multiple criteria. Is that true?

Comment: @HassanAlmaateeq yes, you can have multiple criteria

Answer (score 0):

`arrayformula(countifs(REGEXMATCH(A1:A100," (?i)apple|orange"), true, B1:B100, "banana"))`